# How can I finding the index of a record with SQL or Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, but could relate to other databases as well probably.

If I had the following data (table t):

```
id text  date
1 Data1 2/1/2009
2 Data2 2/2/2009
3 Data3 2/3/2009
4 Data4 2/4/2009
5 Data5 2/5/2009
```

How could I find the index of a certain record?

indexOf(select id from t where id = 1) = 0

or

indexOf(select id from t where date = '2/4/2009') = 3

I think it has something to do with ROW_Number() but not really sure...

Comment: When you say, "IndexOf" do you mean where it appears in your resultset?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the index?

Comment: yeah, essentially I have the value of when a person last viewed a forum topic.  From there I want to then select the range from when they last viewed to the next 20 or so posts.

Comment: You can do that with the TOP keyword and an ORDER BY if that's all that you need to do. If you're going to do paging then using ROW_NUMBER() might be better, but if that's the case then you should research paging methods to find one that fits your situation.

Comment: Already have the paging stuff, but this will tell me which page I'm currently on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ROW_NUMBER` is exactly what you want to leverage along with the `OVER` clause. You can accomplish what you are trying to do using a sub-query or a CTE such as this:

```
;WITH Q as (
    SELECT id, text, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) as RowNumber 
    FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM Q WHERE RowNumber = 3
```

Comment: Looks easy enough, I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: I think I just don't need the WITH Q parts, but this did the trick.  PS was also correct, but left out the "RowNumber" which I guess I'll rename to "Index".  But sort of a shared answer...  :)

Comment: Yep ps did the same w/ sub-query... i just gravitate to CTE's more these days for some reason. More readable to me :)

Comment: if you ask me, i will also recommend the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Edit
select * from  (select ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by id) -1 as Index,* from table) a
where --condition